# left join with and in HQL

Tags: sql, hql, left-join

I have a following working SQL query:

```
    SELECT count(*) 
      FROM A a 
           LEFT OUTER JOIN B b 
                ON a.id = b.aid 
                AND a.x = 700 AND b.y = 800
    WHERE a.type = 1 AND b.type = 2;
```

I want to use an HQL equivalent.

I've tried the following but it doesn't work (compilation):

```
    SELECT count(*) 
      FROM A AS a 
           LEFT JOIN B AS b 
           AND a.x = 700 AND b.y = 800
     WHERE a.type = 1 AND b.type = 2;
```

W/o the "and a.x = 700 and b.y = 800" part it works fine.

Can you please advise?

p.s.
I need the "and a.x = 700 and b.y = 800" part before the "where" cause it's indexed and partitiouned, and I need the indexes and partitions to be used during join.

thanx,
Pavel.

---

Hi,

It seems that my problem is more complex than the usual case, so I"ll just post the exact code:

```
@Entity
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = HFrEvent.COL_EVENT_ID))
@Table(name = HFrEvent.TBL_HFREVENT)
public class HFrEvent extends HOrgEntity {
..
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
    @JoinColumn(name = COL_EVENT_ID)
    public List<HFrEventKeys> getEventKeys() {
        return eventKeys;
    }
..
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "HFREVENTKEYS")
public class HFrEventKeys extends HOrgEntity {
..
}
```

The following query works, although there is no explicit "on" statement:
    select count(event) from HFrEvent as event left join event.eventKeys as key where event.orgFields.customerId = 110 AND event.orgFields.institutionId = 121 and key.orgFields.customerId = 110 AND key.orgFields.institutionId = 121 and key.name=:name and key.value=:value and event.eventType = 1113;

I want to move some the customerid and institutionid into the join part.

the following not compiles:

```
SELECT count(event) 
  FROM HFrEvent AS event 
       LEFT JOIN event.eventKeys AS key 
                 ON event.orgFields.customerId = 110 
                AND event.orgFields.institutionId = 121 
                AND key.orgFields.customerId = 110 
                AND key.orgFields.institutionId = 121 
 WHERE     key.name=:name 
       AND key.value=:value 
       AND event.eventType = 1113;
```

thank you,
Pavel.

Comment: `AND a.x = 700 AND b.y = 800` is a typo, right? It should be `ON`, otherwise your HQL wouldn't compile at all.

Comment: hi, i've added explanation. thanx!